# Laravel: Count integer value inside array from JSON

Tags: php, json, laravel

I'm trying to count integer value from JSON: https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json but I got 1 for each key. What I expect is to count the total 'confirmed' from all countries by date as a key.

Here's my controller:

```
$client = new Client();$request = $client->get('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json');
$response = $request->getBody()->getContents();
$posts_dates = json_decode($response, true);

$confirmed_array = array();

if ( ! empty( $posts_dates ) ) {
    foreach ( $posts_dates as $key => $val ) { 
        foreach ( ((array)$posts_dates)[$key] as $data ) {
            $date_confirmed = new \DateTime( $data['date'] );
            $day = $date_confirmed->format( 'd M y' );
            $confirmed = count((array)$data['confirmed']);
            $confirmed_array [ $day ] = $confirmed;
        }

    } 
}
return $confirmed_array;
```

Here's the result:

```
{
"22 Jan 20": 1,
"23 Jan 20": 1,
"24 Jan 20": 1,
"25 Jan 20": 1,
"26 Jan 20": 1,
"27 Jan 20": 1,
"28 Jan 20": 1,
"29 Jan 20": 1,
"30 Jan 20": 1,
"31 Jan 20": 1,
....
}
```

**UPDATE**

I want to get the output to looks like below:

```
{
  "date": [
     "22 Jan 20",
     "23 Jan 20",
     "24 Jan 20",
     "25 Jan 20",
     .....
   ],
  "total_confirmed": [
     555,
     653,
     941,
     1434,
     .....
   ],
   "max_value_of_total_confirmed": 12214
}
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code just loops through each countries data and then for each date it adds the data to the result array...

```
foreach ( $posts_dates as $country => $data )   {
    foreach ( $data as $date => $dateData )    {
        if ( !isset($confirmed_array[$dateData['date']]) )  {
            $confirmed_array[$dateData['date']] = 0;
        }
        $confirmed_array[$dateData['date']] += $dateData['confirmed'];
    }
}
```

Update:

For the new format, you just need to extract the data from the array so far...

```
$output = ["date" => array_keys($confirmed_array),
    "total_confirmed" => array_values($confirmed_array),
    "max_value_of_total_confirmed" => max($confirmed_array)
];
```

Comment: thanks for your help, it works!!!! but could you please see my updated post? :)

Comment: Hi Nigel, I wonder is it possible to grouping those data by week (not a day)? something like W1 Jan, W2 Jan, W3 Jan, etc?

Comment: It may be worth asking a new question for this.

Comment: Hi Nigel, could you please help me to get the same result as my updated post, but with this kind of json: https://corona.lmao.ninja/v2/historical ? been trying for 2 days and I still didn't understand how to count inside loop array :(